# Plotly: How to create faceted bar plots including a dropdown menu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1':[0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6], 'var2': [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6],
                   'facet_var': ['sd_1', 'sd_1', 'ctrl_1', 'ctrl_1', 'ctrl_1'],
                   'value_facet': ['a', 'b', 'a','b','c']})
```

I would like to create an `html` with `barplots` of `var1` and `var2` (selected from a dropdown menu) faceted by `facet_var`. The `x_values` of the barplots would be the `value_facet` and the `height` of the `barplots` would be the `var1` or `var2` depending on the selection from the dropdown menu

Any ideas how to do something like that using `plotly` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is most likely fully doable, but there are more than a few confusing elements in your question. The question title says `Histogram`, but you're talking about `barplots` in the question itself. So no binning then? Further, the term `facets` lends iself best to `plotly.express (px)`. And `px` works best with data of a long format. And you've provided a dataset that's more of a wide format since you've got columns with values of a single categeoy for `var1` and `var2`:

```
    var1    var2    facet_var   value_facet
0   0.2     1.2     sd_1        a
1   0.3     1.3     sd_1        b
2   0.4     1.4     ctrl_1      a
3   0.5     1.5     ctrl_1      b
4   0.6     1.6     ctrl_1      c
```

And that's a format that's normally better suited for `plotly.graph_objects (go)`. And in that case we'd be more likely talking about `subplots` and not `facets`. And one more thing. The number of dimensions in your dataset doesn't really justify a faceted bar plot. Meaning that all dimensions of your dataset would be fully visualized using a grouped and faceted bar plot like this `px.bar(df, x='value_facet', y='value', color='variable', facet_col='facet_var')`:

**Plot 1:** All data dimensions, but no drop-down

[image]

But to answer your question, assuming that you'd not like to use a histogram (with binned values) but a ***barplot with a dropdown menu***, the code snippet below will produce the following plots for options `var1` and `var2` in the dropdown menu:

**Plot 2:** `var1`

[image]

**Plot 3:** `var2`

[image]

One particulary important line in the complete code snippet below is:

```
df=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['facet_var', 'value_facet'], value_vars=['var1', 'var2'])
```

This turns the dataset from the semi-wide format you've provided into data of a long format that's better suited for `px`:

```
    facet_var   value_facet variable    value
0   sd_1        a           var1    0.2
1   sd_1        b           var1    0.3
2   ctrl_1      a           var1    0.4
3   ctrl_1      b           var1    0.5
4   ctrl_1      c           var1    0.6
5   sd_1        a           var2    1.2
6   sd_1        b           var2    1.3
7   ctrl_1      a           var2    1.4
8   ctrl_1      b           var2    1.5
9   ctrl_1      c           var2    1.6
```

**Complete code:**

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1':[0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6], 'var2': [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6],
                   'facet_var': ['sd_1', 'sd_1', 'ctrl_1', 'ctrl_1', 'ctrl_1'],
                   'value_facet': ['a', 'b', 'a','b','c']})

df=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['facet_var', 'value_facet'], value_vars=['var1', 'var2'])

df1=df[df['variable']=='var1']
df2=df[df['variable']=='var2']

### all dimensions, no drop-downs  ###################################################
# PLot 1
#fig = px.bar(df, x='value_facet', y='value', color='variable', facet_col='facet_var')
#fig.show()
######################################################################################

# Figure with dropdown menu to produce plot 2 and plot 3
fig = px.bar(df1, x='value_facet', y='value', color='variable', facet_col='facet_var')


updatemenus = [
    {
        'buttons': [
            {
                'method': 'update',
                'label': 'var 1',
                'args': [
                    {'y': [df1[(df1['facet_var'] == 'sd_1')]['value'],
                           df1[(df1['facet_var'] == 'ctrl_1')]['value']]},
                ]
            },
            {
                'method': 'update',
                'label': 'var 2',
                'args': [
                    {'y': [df2[(df2['facet_var'] == 'sd_1')]['value'],
                           df2[(df2['facet_var'] == 'ctrl_1')]['value']]},
                ]
            }
        ],
        'direction': 'down',
        'showactive': True,
    }
]

fig.update_layout(updatemenus=updatemenus)
fig.show()
```